# Combining Javascript Validation Functions

Tags: javascript

Alright I need help combining the two JavaScript Functions... I have tried multiple times and am not coming up with any luck. There almost identical functions except the fact that I change one number so that it thinks there different textboxes. I tried putting a variable in its place but then it always only validates to the ending number of the loop. Please show me how I may be able to combine these two functions. (Its my only work around and I can not find any examples similar to mine)

First:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var QnoText = ['abc_1'];  // add IDs here for questions with optional text input

function doSubmit_1() {
  var ids_1 = '';
  flag_1 = true;
    for (i=0; i<QnoText.length; i++) {
      CkStatus = document.getElementById(QnoText[i]).checked;
      ids_1 = QnoText[i]+'Certificate_1';
      if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids_1).value == '') {
        alert('Please enter certificate number 1.');
        document.getElementById(ids_1).focus();
        flag_1 = false;
        alert('return flag_1');
  }
 }
return flag_1;
}

</script>
```

Second:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var QnoText = ['abc_2'];  // add IDs here for questions with optional text input

function doSubmit_2() {
  var ids_2 = '';
  flag_2 = true;
    for (i=0; i<QnoText.length; i++) {
      CkStatus = document.getElementById(QnoText[i]).checked;
      ids_2 = QnoText[i]+'Certificate_2';
      if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids_2).value == '') {
        alert('Please enter certificate number 2.');
        document.getElementById(ids_2).focus();
        flag_2 = false;
        alert('return flag_2');
  }
 }
return flag_2;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter in your function with the number of the textbox, like this:

```
var QnoText = ['abc_2'];  // add IDs here for questions with optional text input

function doSubmit(n) {
  var ids = '';
  flag = true;
    for (i=0; i<QnoText.length; i++) {
      CkStatus = document.getElementById(QnoText[i]).checked;
      ids = QnoText[i]+'Certificate_' + n;
      if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids).value == '') {
        alert('Please enter certificate number ' + n + '.');
        document.getElementById(ids).focus();
        flag = false;
        alert('return flag_' + n);
  }
 }
return flag;
}

doSubmit(1); // for your submit 1
doSubmit(2); // for your submit 2
```

Is this what you wanted? because is not very clear. If is not feel free to explain.